# JUnit test with dynamic number of tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, parameterized-unit-test

In our project I have several [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) tests that e.g. take every file from a directory and run a test on it. If I implement a `testEveryFileInDirectory` method in the `TestCase` this shows up as only one test that may fail or succeed. But I am interested in the results on each individual file. How can I write a `TestCase` / `TestSuite` such that each file shows up as a separate test e.g. in the graphical TestRunner of Eclipse? (Coding an explicit test method for each file is not an option.)

Compare also the question [ParameterizedTest with a name in Eclipse Testrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385925/parameterizedtest-with-a-name-in-eclipse-testrunner).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Take a look at **Parameterized Tests** in JUnit 4.

Actually I did this a few days ago. I'll try to explain ...

First build your test class normally, as you where just testing with one input file.
Decorate your class with:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
```

Build one constructor that takes the input that will change in every test call (in this case it may be the file itself)

Then, build a static method that will return a `Collection` of arrays. Each array in the collection will contain the input arguments for your class constructor e.g. the file. Decorate this method with:

```
@Parameters
```

Here's a sample class.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {

    private File file;

    public ParameterizedTest(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {  }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {  }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        // load the files as you want
        Object[] fileArg1 = new Object[] { new File("path1") };
        Object[] fileArg2 = new Object[] { new File("path2") };

        Collection<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        data.add(fileArg1);
        data.add(fileArg2);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Also check this [example](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/paul_duvall/2007/04/take_heed_of_mixing_junit_4_s_parameterized_tests)

Comment: Thanks! The JUnit 4 Method is better than the JUnit 3 Method given in another answer, since the JUnit 3 confuses the eclipse test runner and with JUnit 4 Method you can re-execute the tests etc.

I am only wondering how I can have eclipse show a name for the test - it only shows [0], [1] etc.

Comment: @hstoerr, Looks like this will be in the next release of JUnit :-) https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/commit/3a5c9f2731462e36dd1c173ea8840d7b9b34b0ab

Comment: How would you transform this for if you wanted each run [with a different data combination] to modify the name of thes test run? [I.e. Path1 file would be tested as: test1Path1, test2Path?

Comment: ^ Updated link: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/commit/3a5c9f2731462e36dd1c173ea8840d7b9b34b0ab

Answer (score 27):

**JUnit 3**

```
public class XTest extends TestCase {

    public File file;

    public XTest(File file) {
        super(file.toString());
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void testX() {
        fail("Failed: " + file);
    }

}

public class XTestSuite extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("XTestSuite");
        File[] files = new File(".").listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            suite.addTest(new XTest(file));
        }
        return suite;
    }

}
```

**JUnit 4**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestY {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getFiles() {
        Collection<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (File f : new File(".").listFiles()) {
            Object[] arr = new Object[] { f };
            params.add(arr);
        }
        return params;
    }

    private File file;

    public TestY(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Test
    public void testY() {
        fail(file.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Junit 5 Parameterized Tests**

[JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) parameterized tests support this by allowing the use of a [method as data source](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource):

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("fileProvider")
void testFile(File f) {
    // Your test comes here
}

static Stream<File> fileProvider() {
    return Arrays.asList(new File(".").list()).stream();
}
```

**JUnit 5 DynamicTests**

[JUnit 5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests) also supports this through the notion of a `DynamicTest`, which is to be generated in a `@TestFactory`, by means of the static method `dynamicTest`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestFactory;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest.dynamicTest;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

@TestFactory
public Stream<DynamicTest> testFiles() {
    return Arrays.asList(new File(".").list())
            .stream()
            .map((file) -> dynamicTest(
                    "Test for file: " + file,
                    () -> { /* Your test comes here */ }));
}
```

The tests run in your IDE (IntelliJ here) will be displayed like this:

[image: Output in IntelliJ]

Answer (score 3):

Should be possible in JUnit 3 by inheriting from `TestSuite` and overriding the `tests()` method to list the files and for each return an instance of a subclass of `TestCase` that takes the filename as constructor parameter and has a test method that tests the file given in the constructor.

In JUnit 4 it might be even easier.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [JUnitParams library](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams), so you would have a few more (cleaner) options:

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {

    @org.junit.Test
    @junitparams.Parameters(method = "data")
    public void test1(File file) throws Exception {  }

    @org.junit.Test
    @junitparams.Parameters(method = "data")
    public void test2(File file) throws Exception {  }

    public static File[] data() {
        return new File[] { new File("path1"), new File("path2") };
    }
}
```

---

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {

    @org.junit.Test
    @junitparams.Parameters(value = { "path1", "path2" })
    public void test1(String path) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(path);
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    @junitparams.Parameters(value = { "path1", "path2" })
    public void test2(String path) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(path);
    }
}
```

---

You can see more [samples of usage here](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/Samples_of_Usage_Test.java).

In addition [about JUnitParams, why writting parameterized tests with it is easier and more readable](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams#about):

> JUnitParams project adds a new runner to JUnit and provides much
>   easier and readable parametrised tests for JUnit >=4.6.
>
> Main differences to standard JUnit Parametrised runner:
>
> - more explicit - params are in test method params, not class fields
> - less code - you don't need a constructor to set up parameters
> - you can mix parametrised with non-parametrised methods in one class
> - params can be passed as a CSV string or from a parameters provider class
> - parameters provider class can have as many parameters providing methods as you want, so that you can group different cases
> - you can have a test method that provides parameters (no external classes or statics anymore)
> - you can see actual parameter values in your IDE (in JUnit's Parametrised it's only consecutive numbers of parameters)

Answer (score 1):

If TestNG is an option, you could use [Parameters with DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).

Each individual file's test will have its result shown in the text-based report or Eclipse's TestNG plugin UI. The number of total tests run will count each of your files individually.

This behavior differs from JUnit [Theories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories), in which all results are lumped under one "theory" entry and only count as 1 test. If you want separate result reporting in JUnit, you can try [Parameterized Tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests).

### Test and inputs

```
public class FileTest {

    @DataProvider(name="files")
    public File[][] getFiles(){
        return new File[][] {
            { new File("file1") },
            { new File("file2") }
        };
        // or scan a directory
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="files")
    public void testFile(File file){
        //run tests on file
    }
}
```

### Example output

```
PASSED: testFile(file1)
PASSED: testFile(file2)

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: I don't know about theories, but parameterized tests in JUnit are shown separately in eclipse, not lumped together.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up writing a simple JUnit 4 runner that allows med to dynamically generate tests.

https://github.com/kimble/junit-test-factory