# ParameterizedTest with a name in Eclipse Testrunner

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, parameterized-unit-test

When you run a JUnit 4 ParameterizedTest with the Eclipse TestRunner, the graphical representation is rather dumb: for each test you have a node called `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.
Is it possible give the tests `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. explicit names? Implementing a `toString` method for the tests does not seem to help.

(This is a follow-up question to [JUnit test with dynamic number of tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358802/junit-test-with-dynamic-number-of-tests).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit4 now [allows specifying a name attribute](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) to the Parameterized annotation, such that you can specify a naming pattern from the index and toString methods of the arguments. E.g.:

```
@Parameters(name = "{index}: fib({0})={1}")
public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 },
            { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 } });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think there's nothing *built in* in jUnit 4 to do this.

I've implemented a solution. I've built my own `Parameterized` class based on the existing one:

```
public class MyParameterized extends TestClassRunner {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public static @interface Parameters {
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public static @interface Name {
    }

    public static Collection<Object[]> eachOne(Object... params) {
        List<Object[]> results = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (Object param : params)
            results.add(new Object[] { param });
        return results;
    }

    // TODO: single-class this extension

    private static class TestClassRunnerForParameters extends TestClassMethodsRunner {
        private final Object[] fParameters;

        private final Class<?> fTestClass;

        private Object instance;

        private final int fParameterSetNumber;

        private final Constructor<?> fConstructor;

        private TestClassRunnerForParameters(Class<?> klass, Object[] parameters, int i) throws Exception {
            super(klass);
            fTestClass = klass;
            fParameters = parameters;
            fParameterSetNumber = i;
            fConstructor = getOnlyConstructor();
            instance = fConstructor.newInstance(fParameters);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
            return instance;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getName() {
            String name = null;
            try {
                Method m = getNameMethod();
                if (m != null)
                    name = (String) m.invoke(instance);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return String.format("[%s]", (name == null ? fParameterSetNumber : name));
        }

        @Override
        protected String testName(final Method method) {
            String name = null;
            try {
                Method m = getNameMethod();
                if (m != null)
                    name = (String) m.invoke(instance);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return String.format("%s[%s]", method.getName(), (name == null ? fParameterSetNumber : name));
        }

        private Constructor<?> getOnlyConstructor() {
            Constructor<?>[] constructors = getTestClass().getConstructors();
            assertEquals(1, constructors.length);
            return constructors[0];
        }

        private Method getNameMethod() throws Exception {
            for (Method each : fTestClass.getMethods()) {
                if (Modifier.isPublic((each.getModifiers()))) {
                    Annotation[] annotations = each.getAnnotations();
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        if (annotation.annotationType() == Name.class) {
                            if (each.getReturnType().equals(String.class))
                                return each;
                            else
                                throw new Exception("Name annotated method doesn't return an object of type String.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    // TODO: I think this now eagerly reads parameters, which was never the
    // point.

    public static class RunAllParameterMethods extends CompositeRunner {
        private final Class<?> fKlass;

        public RunAllParameterMethods(Class<?> klass) throws Exception {
            super(klass.getName());
            fKlass = klass;
            int i = 0;
            for (final Object each : getParametersList()) {
                if (each instanceof Object[])
                    super.add(new TestClassRunnerForParameters(klass, (Object[]) each, i++));
                else
                    throw new Exception(String.format("%s.%s() must return a Collection of arrays.", fKlass.getName(), getParametersMethod().getName()));
            }
        }

        private Collection<?> getParametersList() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, Exception {
            return (Collection<?>) getParametersMethod().invoke(null);
        }

        private Method getParametersMethod() throws Exception {
            for (Method each : fKlass.getMethods()) {
                if (Modifier.isStatic(each.getModifiers())) {
                    Annotation[] annotations = each.getAnnotations();
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        if (annotation.annotationType() == Parameters.class)
                            return each;
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No public static parameters method on class " + getName());
        }
    }

    public MyParameterized(final Class<?> klass) throws Exception {
        super(klass, new RunAllParameterMethods(klass));
    }

    @Override
    protected void validate(MethodValidator methodValidator) {
        methodValidator.validateStaticMethods();
        methodValidator.validateInstanceMethods();
    }

}
```

**To be used like:**

```
@RunWith(MyParameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {
    private File file;
    public ParameterizedTest(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {}

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {}

    @Name
    public String getName() {
        return "coolFile:" + file.getName();
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        // load the files as you want
        Object[] fileArg1 = new Object[] { new File("path1") };
        Object[] fileArg2 = new Object[] { new File("path2") };

        Collection<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        data.add(fileArg1);
        data.add(fileArg2);
        return data;
    }
}
```

This implies that I instantiate the test class earlier. I hope this won't cause any errors ... I guess I should test the tests :)

Comment: FYI: This answer is still correct for JUnit 4.0, but fortunately adding customized names is possible in JUnit 4.11.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143872/103814

Answer (score 2):

A code-less though not that comfortable solution is to pass enough context information to identify the test in assert messages. You will still see just testXY[0] failed but the detailed message tells you which one was that.

```
assertEquals("Not the expected decision for the senator " + this.currentSenatorName + " and the law " + this.votedLaw, 
expectedVote, actualVote);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [JUnitParams library](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) (as I have [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360402/1064325)), the parameterized tests will have their stringified parameters as their own default test names.

Moreover, [you can see in their samples](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/Samples_of_Usage_Test.java), that JUnitParams also allows you to have a custom test name by using `@TestCaseName`:

> ```
> @Test
> @Parameters({ "1,1", "2,2", "3,6" })
> @TestCaseName("factorial({0}) = {1}")
> public void custom_names_for_test_case(int argument, int result) { }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> @Test
> @Parameters({ "value1, value2", "value3, value4" })
> @TestCaseName("[{index}] {method}: {params}")
> public void predefined_macro_for_test_case_name(String param1, String param2) { }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There's no hint that this feature is or will be implemented. I would request this feature because it's nice to have.