# Junit 4 custom test class description

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am using the **@Parameterized annotation** to run a test class over and over again against different test files.

The problem is that in my IDE/build server the  tests show up as **"MapSimulationTest" 0-x**.

How can I have a method that provides **JUnit 4** with a custom *name* for each instance of my **MapSimulationTest** class?  In this case it would be the *filename* the test is being run against.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/change-test-name-of-parameterized-tests help?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/change-test-name-of-parameterized-tests