# How to get clear report for parameterized Junit-tests while run through ANT?

Tags: ant, junit4

I have a JUnit test, which uses the Parameterized runner. I have two parameters to be passed (country names) Once this Junit runs in the HTML report for each parameter it gives the result. But it gives the result with testname1[0], testname1[1]..... and so forth for parameter. (for each parameter it will add [] after test name )

I want to customize the result for example 2 parameters are Country names. I would like to have something like CountryName1 - under that testName1. Then CountryName2.. testName.

Is there a way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an [issue for JUnit](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/issues/44), which proposes to extend the Parameterized runner to support better test names. Unfortunately the issue is not solved yet.

An alternative is to use [CallbackParams](http://callbackparams.org/).

#### See also

> [Change test name of parameterized tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/change-test-name-of-parameterized-tests)

Answer (score 1):

With version 4.11 of JUnit, it is now possible to rename the parameterized tests. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143872/463824) which tells how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

recently i started [zohhak](http://zohhak.googlecode.com) project. it lets you write:

```java
@TestWith({
   "25 USD, 7",
   "38 GBP, 2",
   "null,   0"
})
public void testMethod(Money money, int anotherParameter) {
   ...
}
```

and each invocation is reported with parameters - check screenshot on main page