# Junit 4 - running all the tests in a test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, interface, junit4

I have been setting up some contract JUnit 4 tests (following advice in answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157042/java-contract-tests)) - e.g. if I have an interface (I've included generics in the example, since I'm using them in my project) - but, this is a significantly simplified example:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
  public T myMethod();
}
```

I can create an abstract contract test - e.g.:

```
public abstract class AbstractMyInterfaceTest<T> {

  private final MyInterface<T> _impl;  
  // plus, store stuff to test against;

  public AbstractMyInterfaceTest(MyInterface<T> impl, ... stuff to test against){
    _impl = impl;
    // stuff to test against...
  } 

  @Test
  public void testMyMethod(){
    // test some stuff...
  }
}
```

...and extend this abstract test class for each implementation (which I am running with `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`). I'm also passing some variables to test the implementation of the interface against into the abstract test class.

However, in actuality, some interfaces return objects that are implementations of other interfaces, and I would like to be able to test this implementation using the abstract contract class for that interface (...and against the relevant variables). For example, a method in `MyInterface` might return an Iterator - which is an interface. I have a separate `AbstractIteratorTest`, which runs a contract test for Iterator against a set of values, and I want to check that the `Iterator` returned by the implementations of `MyInterface` passes the contract tests in `AbstractIteratorTest` with the expected set of values.

At the moment, I'm adding the following to the abstract test classes:

```
// N.b. not setting @Test - so doesn't run all tests twice...
public void runTests(){
  testMyMethod();
  // etc.
}
```

However, this doesn't run each test independently (e.g. running `setUp()` before each test method), so there are problems if those contract tests expect the implementation to be in a particular state for each test. (A specific example would be testing implementations of the `Iterator` interface, where each test method can change the state of the tested `Iterator`)

Is there was a better way of doing this, perhaps making use of features in JUnit 4?

I've seen stuff about the `@RunWith(Suite.class)` annotation, but that seems to be about running multiple test classes from a single test class, and doesn't allow you to pass variables into the different test classes that are being run. There may be a way to use this  `Suite` to solve my problem, but I'm not sure what it is...

Comment: You might like to explain the "some interfaces return objects that are implementations of other interfaces, and I would like to be able to test this implementation using the abstract contract class for that interface" bit more precisely. I think i understand that, but i could have it wrong.

Comment: Does a run of all the tests in `AbstractMyInterfaceTest` kick off a single run of `AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest`, or multiple? Is `MyInterface` really as simple as you indicate, just a factory for another object?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're subclassing your abstract test class, you don't need to use `Parameterized`. You could use `Parameterized` instead of subclassing, but you're unlikely to need both. Unless you want to test multiple instances of each implementation, which i will demonstrate below!

One way to do this would be to make the tests for returned instances simply be more subclasses or parameterisations of `AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest`.

Say you have:

```
public abstract class AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest {

    private AnotherInterface instance;

    protected AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest(AnotherInterface instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Test
    public void everythingIsOkay() {...}

}
```

And you had:

```
public class Pony implements AnotherInterface { ... }
public class PonyProducingMyInterface implements MyInterface<Pony> { ... }
```

You could write:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PonyTest extends AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Pony> ponies() {
        return Arrays.asList(
            new Pony(), // base case
            new PonyProducingMyInterface().myMethod() // testing the factory
        );
    }

    public PonyTest(Pony instance) {
        super(pony);
    }

}
```

This is admittedly a bit weird, though, because the `new PonyProducingMyInterface().myMethod()` case is really a test for `PonyProducingMyInterface`, but is classified under `AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest`.

The only approach i can think of that would make use of the `AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest` tests in some subclass of `AbstractMyInterfaceTest` would be to write a custom `ParentRunner` which knew how to set up instances of `AbstractAnotherInterfaceTest` as children of instances of `AbstractMyInterfaceTest`. You'd probably want to make that a bit generic, using annotations to guide the process.

Comment: Re. your first point, I am running my sub-tests with Parameterized, because I want to test multiple instances of each implementation - that was the point of my previous question referenced at the top.

Comment: Aha. Sorry, i read the previous question, but not carefully enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution of using the `MyInterfaceImpl.getOtherInterface()` as a parameter in the `OtherInterfaceTest` is, as you say, a bit weird - it also doesn't work in my project because there's no guarantee of which implementation of `OtherInterface` will be returned by `MyInterfaceImpl`. Your other solution - a custom `ParentRunner` - looks like overkill.

Comment: It may look like overkill, but i believe it is the only way to run the tests you want as individual JUnit tests. Ultimately, it is the runners which enumerate the set of tests (as well as run them - JUnit doesn't separate those concerns well), so if you want to add tests of a kind JUnit doesn't know about natively, then you have to write a new runner.