# JUnit tests in files

Tags: java, junit

I used to write JUnit tests as methods, such as:

```
public class TextualEntailerTest {
  @Test test1() {...}
  @Test test2() {...}
  @Test test3() {...}
}
```

Since most of the test cases has a similar structure, I decided to be "data-driven", and put the contents of the tests in XML files. So, I created a method "testFromFile(file)" and changed my test to:

```
public class TextualEntailerTest {
  @Test test1() { testFromFile("test1.xml"); }
  @Test test2() { testFromFile("test2.xml"); }
  @Test test3() { testFromFile("test3.xml"); }
}
```

As I add more and more tests, I become tired of adding a line for each new test file I add. Of course I can put all files in a single test:

```
public class TextualEntailerTest {
  @Test testAll() { 
     foreach (String file: filesInFolder) 
       testFromFile(file); 
  }
}
```

However, I prefer that each file will be a separate test, because this way JUnit gives nice statistics about the number of files passed and failed.

So, my question is: how to tell JUnit to run separate tests, where each test is of the form "testFromFile(file)", for all files in a given folder?

Comment: Why not use junit's data-driven test functionality?

Comment: Sounds interesting, what is this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class JunitTest {

     private String filename;

     public JunitTest(String filename) {
        this.filename= filename;
     }

     @Parameters
     public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
       Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { "file1.xml" }, { "file2.xml" } };
       return Arrays.asList(data);
     }

     @Test
     public void Test() {
       System.out.println("Test name:" + filename);
     }


}
```

Comment: Neat! The only problem is, the JUnit panel shows the tests as "Test[0]", "Test[1]", etc., instead of showing meaningful names (the file names, for example). So, when looking at the panel, there is no easy way to know which tests failed. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/changing-names-of-parameterized-tests

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Theories` where the files are `@DataPoints` so you won't need to loop in your test and will allow for setup and cleanup after each file. But it will still be reported as such.

Theories also have the issue that they fail fast (quit after first failure) as your test above does. I find that this is not good practice since it can hide a situation where you have multiple bugs. I recommend using seperate tests or use the loop with an `ErrorCollector`. I really wish `Theories` had `ErrorCollector` built in.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but may be these can help you.
[Reference1](http://www.kumaranuj.com/2012/08/junits-parameterized-runner-and-data.html) [Reference2](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you happen to know if parameterized tests fail fast?

Comment: Didn't get you. Some time ago there was such requirement in one of the projects and we looked at possible solutions but didn't use it. That is why I just tried to give some hint if that can help.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it is a good suggestion and I gave you credit. I was just wondering if you knew. I will try it out myself to see and post the results.

Comment: So, first Parameterized tests give you a seperate test per set of parameters so I think this is what @Erel is looking for. Also, they do not fail fast as Theories do which is really nice. Finally, if used in combination with the Enclosed runner you can create multiple tests with different parameters. NICE!

Comment: Yes, I got that @Jhon, but I didn't get what did you mean by 'fail fast' but I now I got that too. BTW, thanks for the credit and improving the answer.