# How to specify label to a Parameterized junit run

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, parameterized

In Eclipse, while using the Parameterized runner in a junit test class, each run is noted by a number (0, 1, etc.)

Is there a way to replace this number with a proper label?

**PS:** I am using a `JUNIT` version **4.8** older than 4.11 so the `@Parameters` does not take any argument

**Test Case:**

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getLabels() {
        List<Object[]> labels = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        labels.add(new Object[] {"Toto"});
        labels.add(new Object[] {"Titi"});
        return labels;
    }

    private final String label;

    public TestClass(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing names of parameterized tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/changing-names-of-parameterized-tests)

Comment: @MartinSchröder Nope. I don't want to change the Test Class name or the test method. I just want to replace the numbered indices with a String. I have already checked the one you pointed at and it's not a duplicate!

Comment: @MartinSchröder Also, the solution is only available since junti 4.11 while I am using an older version of junit 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to easily identify the individual test cases in a Parameterized test, you may provide a **name** using the @Parameters annotation.
This name is allowed to contain placeholders that are replaced at runtime:

{index}: the current parameter index
{0}, {1}, …: the first, second, and so on, parameter value

See example here:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: Hello, the name attribute was added in junit 4.11. I am using 4.8 so it won't work

Comment: Is there  reason that you are sticking to this version and don't upgrade to the latest?

Comment: Version management is not handled by me nor am i allowed to change it

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized test is calling `toString()` internally, which does not work for us because some our implementations do not allow `toString()` and throw an exception.

In this case, the test names will be

```
TestClass
    testMethod
        [1] Argument1.toString()
        [2] Argument2.toString()
        [3]
```

I created an object wrapper for my argument that holds the original object, and overrides `toString` method.

Here is the example.

```
private static List<LabelArgument> getLabels() {
    List<LabelArgument> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    labels.add(LabelArgument.of(new SimpleLabel("Hi there")));
    labels.add(LabelArgument.of(new LabelExtended2D("Good bye!")));

    // Label toString throws an exception
    labels.add(LabelArgument.of(new Label("Simple"))); 

    return labels;
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getLabels")
void testLabel(LabelArgument labelArgument ) {
    var label = labelArgument.getLabel();
    // Do the test
}

private static class LabelArgument {

    private Label label;

    private LabelArgument(Label label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public static LabelArgument of(Label label) {
        return new LabelArgument(label);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

It will produce

```
TestClass
    testAllLabels
        [1] SimpleLabel
        [2] LabelExtended2D
        [3] Label
```