# Add parameter to test title in allure

Tags: testing, junit, allure

I use Allure with jUnit. In parametrized test I see parameter in the title
[image]

When I want to provide custom title via `@Title` annotation, these parameters is not shown. I tried to specify parameter as `@Title("Test {0}")` but it didn't work as well.

Is there a way to have custom title and parameter in the test case?

Answer (score 2):

How about setting [name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/changing-names-of-parameterized-tests) to @Parameterized annotation?

```
@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "My cool test {1} {2} {3}")
```

**UPD:** Allure gets **@Title** annotation value as is and does not support neither **{method}** nor **{i}** notation because it's being processed without aspects. Java on its turn does not allow dynamic expressions in annotations.

Comment: I tried and got `Calculation test [My cool test 1]`. But I expected to replace entire title, not brackets content

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend usage of Allure object to update test name at runtime in Allure lifecycle.

```
Allure.getLifecycle().updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setName("updated_test_name"));
```