# Override a pytest parameterized functions name

Tags: python, rename, pytest, fixtures, parameterized

My parameters determine the name of my parameterized pytest. I will be using a some randomized params for these tests. In order for my reporting names in junit to not get messed up, I'd like to create a static name for each parameterized test.

Is it possible?

JUnit seems to have a parameter: [Changing names of parameterized tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/changing-names-of-parameterized-tests)

```
class TestMe:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ("testname", "op", "value"),
        [
            ("testA", "plus", "3"),
            ("testB", "minus", "1"),
        ]
    )
    def test_ops(self, testname, op, value):
```

I tried overwriting `request.node.name` however I can only rename it during test execution.

I'm almost positive I either need to write a plugin or a fixture. What do you think would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're looking for the `ids` argument of [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/parametrize.html):

> list of string ids, or a callable. If strings, each is corresponding
> to the argvalues so that they are part of the test id. If callable, it
> should take one argument (a single argvalue) and return a string or
> return *None*.

Your code would look like

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("testname", "op", "value"),
    [
        ("testA", "plus", "3"),
        ("testB", "minus", "1"),
    ],
    ids=['testA id', 'testB id']
)
def test_industry(self, testname, op, value):
```

Comment: How would I go about addressing the individual test cases `pytest -k test_industry[testA id]` doesn't work...

Comment: or use a lambda function to generate some IDs 
`ids=lambda t: str(t).lstrip()[0:8],`

Comment: Doc examples using `ids` (`pytest.mark.parametrize`) and `id` (`pytest.param`) parameters -- https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids

Answer (score 10):

you can also use pytest parametrize wrapper from: https://github.com/singular-labs/parametrization or on pypi

```
pip install pytest-parametrization
```

your code would look like:

```
from parametrization import Parametrization

class TestMe:
    @Parametrization.autodetect_parameters()
    @Parametrization.case(name="testA", op='plus', value=3)
    @Parametrization.case(name="testB", op='minus', value=1)
    def test_ops(self, op, value):
        ...
```

which is equals to:

```
class TestMe:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ("op", "value"),
        [
            ("plus", "3"),
            ("minus", "1"),
        ],
        ids=['testA', 'testB']
    )
    def test_ops(self, op, value):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you parametrise with your own **custom class** I found it useful to inherit the `str` class. Thus you can control the `ID` in your class without the need to repeat `ids=str` every time.

```
class TestMode(str):
    __test__ = False
    def __new__(cls, name: str, op: str, value: int):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, name)
        obj.name = name
        obj.op = op
        obj.value = value
        ...
        return obj
M1 = TestMode("M1", "plus", 3)
M2 = TestMode("M1", "minus", 1)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("mode", (M1, M2))
def test_good_exbytes_fail_over(mode: TestMode):
    pass
```