# Groovy. Parametrized test with dynamic name

Tags: unit-testing, dynamic, groovy, junit, parameter-passing

I want to implement `groovy` parametrized test, where test names will be built using parameter values. I know how to do it in `java` (also I've found the java answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143872/5728095), but not `groovy`)

So I need to improve my `groovy` parametrized unit test with same option:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized

@RunWith(Parameterized)
class TestSimple {

    String numberA
    String numberB
    String expectedResult

    TestSimple(numA, numB, expected) {
        numberA = numA
        numberB = numB
        expectedResult = expected
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    static data1() {
        [
                [null, "asd|asd|||ASD||ASD", 'result for first case'],
                ['09909', "asd|asd|||ASD||ASD", 'result for second case']

        ]*.toArray()
    }

    @Test
    void testLogonRequest1() throws Exception {
        println numberA + ":" + numberB
    }
}
```

to replace ordered number with parameter value

```
TestSimple
  [0]
    testLogonRequest1[0]
  [1]
    testLogonRequest1[1]
```

Expected result similar to:

```
TestSimple
  [used parameters: <numberA0value>, <numberB0value>]
    testLogonRequest1[expected result: <expectedResult0Value>]
  [used parameters: <numberA1value>, <numberB1value>]
    testLogonRequest1[expected result: <expectedResult1Value>]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it is possible just using `org.junit.runners.Parameterized`, the message in `[]` has to be same, maybe you can write your SuiteClasses to achieve this effect.

Comment: do you have any exception?

Comment: btw. why you did not specified the `data1()` function return type? try to set `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` annotation for your class and fix all the compile errors.

Comment: @daggett no exceptions here. I've not specified types and so on, and done as it is, because of i'm new in groovy :). If I know how to do better, i do it. Is return type important for my issue?

Comment: @aristotll. It seems you know how to do it. Could you pay my attention which annotations i should use for my purpose (I would research them)?

Comment: You can see the source code of `org.junit.runners.Parameterized#createTestWithParameters` and `org.junit.runners.Parameterized#getParametersMethod`, and understand why I say  the message in [] has to be same. It is not an annotation choice problem.

Comment: So you have to write your own version of `org.junit.runners.Parameterized`.

Comment: Is Spock Framework an option?

Comment: I do not know `spock` yet, but if it's useful - of course.