# Run one junit test multiple times with different parameters

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

How can I run a test multiple times with different parameters and have them displayed as separate tests (with different names) in the Junit report?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing names of parameterized tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650894/changing-names-of-parameterized-tests)

Comment: If you are using JUnit 4, please take a look at the duplicate post, otherwise if you are using JUnit 5 take a look at: https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5

Comment: @MedAmine, What version of JUnit you're using? Where do you want your parameters to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Java method that runs the code, if not in your JUnit test case then in the Java file you import. Then for each of the tests you want, you just call it repeatedly with different input arguments and different parameters. See the links you've been given: https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5