# How to write dynamic Test Case

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Suppose, I have a `junit` test class:

```
class MyComponentTest {

  private void test(File file) {...}

  @Test public void test1() {test("test1.txt")}
  @Test public void test2() {test("test2.txt")}
  @Test public void test3() {test("test3.txt")}
}
```

The `test` method reads the input data from the `file` and test the component with the input data.

What if I am changing the `MyComponentTest` ?

```
class MyComponentTest {

  private void test(File file) {...}

  @Test public void testAll() {
    for (String name: dir.list())
      test(new File(name))
  }
}
```

Now I have only one test (`testAll`) instead of three tests (`test1`, `test2`, and `test3`) as it was before. The `Runner` for example will not recognize *three* separate tests as it did in the previous version of the class.

My question is: how to make each `test` method invocation a separate test from the `junit` point of view ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JUnit test with dynamic number of tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358802/junit-test-with-dynamic-number-of-tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you can use [Junit's Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) tests for this it is bit involved and ugly. I suggest you looking at the [spockframework](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) which simplifies this a lot. And there is also another option in TestNG.