# Selenium: dynamic number of tests

Tags: selenium, junit4

We are using JUnit 4 and define our Selenium tests using annotations.  I have a suite where I would like to run one of my tests a random number of times - between 3 and 5 times.  I've tried the techniques described elsewhere on SO to define dynamically the tests to be run ( [JUnit test with dynamic number of tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358802/junit-test-with-dynamic-number-of-tests) ) without luck.

Is this a limitation of Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are sure many ways to do this.
Heres one solution:
You could generate a random number beside generating your JUnitCore and thus write a new suite file and add the "string to your java test class" the amount of the random number in.