# Running tests in sequence when data is provided using dataprovider in testng

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

I provide data to the test using a data provider. The test class has 3 tests. I want the three tests to run in sequence for every instance of data provided by data-provider. I tried the following , but this runs testOne for completely for all the data provided by data-provider and then testTwo and then testThree.

```
public class TestClass{

    @Test(@dataProvider = "getData")
    public void testOne(){
         //Test case logic
      }

    @Test(@dataProvider = "getData")
    public void testTwo(){
         //Test case logic
      }

    @Test(@dataProvider = "getData")
    public void testThree(){
         //Test case logic
      }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData() {
        //data provider code
      }

}
```

Could anyone tell me how to run the three tests for the data instance provided by the data-provider and then run the three tests for the next data instance and so on..

Thanks

Comment: I would think the unit test is wrong if it must rely on the method and test data call order. Can you explain why you need such restriction?

Comment: HI Gedrox ..I am not trying this for a unit test . We are trying to have a functional test a UI level . Each test tests for a particular scenario on the front end. Each test involves opening a browser instance . We do not want to open the browser instance for all the tests as that would result in a delay in the test execution time.

Comment: Maybe this question helps – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358802/junit-test-with-dynamic-number-of-tests.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
public class TestClass {

  @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
  public void allTests() {
    testOne();
    testTwo();
    testThree();
  }

  private void testOne(){
     //Test case logic
  }
  private void testTwo(){
     //Test case logic
  }
  public void testThree(){
     //Test case logic
  }

  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] getData() {
    //data provider code
  }

}
```